# Selenium-webdriver crawler for Service-Now, Automating the search and opening of a task with python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver, automation, web-crawler

I've been trying to get a selenium script to run on service-now.
What I need it to do is just to open SNOW and in my to-do list look for the first task called with a short_description of this exact string "Set Initial Account Passwords".
When I try going to inspect the element I have to do it twice, because the first time it doesn't expand where the element is.

If I copy the selector it looks something like this #row_sc_task_dc9cxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx > td:nth-child(5)

If I copy the element it's this one: Set Initial Account Passwords

NOW, when I try to zero on that element it never finds it.
I even tried logging every element and sub element, every selector, I had it expand every table and whatever I could think of in a file.log and still, can't find either the sc_task, nor the string "Set Initial Account Passwords" nor the "ng-non-bindable"

I've tried everything I could find to read everything in the site, even to read what one can read as text and nothing.

Has anybody had to deal with this at some point?
I'm trying to automate an action and everything works fine, it's just this blessed thing that won't open tickets from the list and, having to specify each task number or what have you will just defeat the purpose of having this automated.

OH, and, I've already tried chatgpt and it's no good, it won't do what I need.
Here are 2 screenshots of what this looks like if that could help in any way.enter image description here

[image]